# C# SerialPort.ReadExisting Error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have hooked a Unity project up to an Arduino board via a com port. I am receiving data from it fine while using `SerialPort.ReadLine()`, however, if i use `SerialPort.ReadExisting()` I get the error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I need to use ReadExisting as my application cant keep up with the rate that the Ardunio board is spitting out data.

I have got ReadExisting working fine in a XNA project, just when used in a unity project i have  issues.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [`DataReceived`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived.aspx) event.  Then inside the event handler, try and call ReadExisting.  The link I posted has an example.

Comment: Unity does not allow you to use the DataReceived event